# Google Game Services for Android Stubborn Error

Tags: java, android, service, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've used SO to help me solve programming frustrations for years now and this feels like the first time I've had an issue that's unique to me alone (or at least that noone else has asked about). Anyway, here's my issue below and I'd be very grateful for any help anyone can offer. :)

I've been trying for the past 24 hours or so to implement Google Game Services in my existing Android app. I followed the instructions provided by Google with regards to setting up the app in the developer console, using the signing certificate key, linking it to my app in the store, put the application ID into my Eclipse project in the location and all of that. I derive from the BaseGameActivity class as recommended and my project compiles fine with no errors. I also use the FacebookSDK and AdMob/Google ads (using the new Google services library). I can't think of anything I haven't done that could explain my error - which is as follows...

When my app opens and attempts to sign in, it pops up and asks for permissions/authorization as normal but once I grant these permissions it says "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.". This has happened every time for the past 24 hours as I've been trying little tweaks here and there hoping to make a difference. I'm 100 % sure there's no problem with my network connection as implied by the error message.

P.S. It did seem to connect/sign in one random time and I got the welcome message but by the time it got to the next activity in my app it seemed to have signed out again and the error message returned. I've also checked from the Google+ side and I can see where I have indeed granted my app permissions (which implies that I did sign in successfully and authorize it properly) so I can't understand the error messages I'm getting within the game itself.

I know this was very long but I wanted to be as thorough with my explanation as possible - can anyone please advice me on how to deal with this? :(

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

//import android.view.Gravity;

//import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
//import com.google.ads.AdSize;
//import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private FrameLayout myLayout;

    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;

    private MainMenuView myView;

    private RotateAnimation buttonRotate, buttonReverseRotate;

    private ImageView start, achievements, highscores;

    protected AdView adView;

    boolean musicStopped = false;
    //private AdView adView;

    String name = "startSt";

    int width, height;

    Intent i; 

    public void onSignInFailed () {

    }

    public void onSignInSucceeded () {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_select);
        i = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class);

        startService(i);



        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("fasf78678fhk");

        //adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        //adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) { 

            display.getSize(size);

            width = size.x;

            height = size.y;

        }

        else {

            width = display.getWidth();

            height = display.getHeight();

        }


        start = new ImageView(this);

        //animview.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions

        start.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width * 0.40), (int)(height * ((double)60/534)));

            params.setMargins((int)(width * 0.30), (int) (height * ((double)280/534)), (int)(width * 0.70), (int)(height * ((double)340/534)));

        //(int)(width * 0.20), (int)(height * 0.01), (int)(width * 0.80), (int)(height * 0.14)

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        start.setLayoutParams(params);


        start.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.startbtn);
    //

        achievements = new ImageView(this);

        //animview.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions

        achievements.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width * 0.40), (int)(height * ((double)53/534)));

        params.setMargins((int)(width * 0.30), (int) (height * ((double)353/534)), (int)(width * 0.70), (int)(height * ((double)408/534)));

        //(int)(width * 0.20), (int)(height * 0.01), (int)(width * 0.80), (int)(height * 0.14)

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        achievements.setLayoutParams(params);

        achievements.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.achievementsbtn);

        //

        highscores = new ImageView(this);

        //animview.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions

        highscores.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width * 0.40), (int)(height * ((double)56/534)));

        params.setMargins((int)(width * 0.30), (int) (height * ((double)422/534)), (int)(width * 0.70), (int)(height * ((double)478/534)));

        //(int)(width * 0.20), (int)(height * 0.01), (int)(width * 0.80), (int)(height * 0.14)

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        highscores.setLayoutParams(params);

        highscores.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highscoresbtn);

        //adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a152709973dcd0d");

        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams LP = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) adView.getLayoutParams();

        //LP.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;

        //adView.setLayoutParams(LP);

        musicStopped = false;

        buttonRotate = new RotateAnimation(-4f, 4f, (float) (0.2 * width), (float) (height * ((double)28/534)));

        buttonRotate.setDuration(1000);

        buttonRotate.setRepeatMode(RotateAnimation.REVERSE);

        buttonRotate.setRepeatCount(1000);

        buttonRotate.setFillEnabled(true);

        buttonRotate.setFillAfter(true);

        //

        buttonReverseRotate = new RotateAnimation(4f, -4f, (float) (0.2 * width), (float) (height * ((double)28/534)));

        buttonReverseRotate.setDuration(1000);

        buttonReverseRotate.setRepeatMode(RotateAnimation.REVERSE);

        buttonReverseRotate.setRepeatCount(1000);

        buttonReverseRotate.setFillEnabled(true);

        buttonReverseRotate.setFillAfter(true);

        buttonReverseRotate.setStartOffset(0);

        //adView.setX(0f);

        //adView.setY((float) (height * 0.8));csd

        myView = new MainMenuView (this, i, width, height);

        myLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

        setContentView(myLayout);

        myLayout.addView(myView);

        myLayout.addView(start);

        myLayout.addView(highscores);

        myLayout.addView(achievements);




        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width), (int)(height * 0.09));
        lp.setMargins((int)(width * 0.0), (int)(height * 0.00), (int)(width * 1), (int)(height * 0.09));

        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        adView.setLayoutParams(lp);








        myLayout.addView(adView);

        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        start.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        achievements.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        highscores.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //FACEBOOK


        //adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          name = "activity result runs";
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.level_select, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;

    }

    public void onBackPressed () {

        stopService(i);

        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    public void showButtons () {

        //start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //achievements.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //highscores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    //public void onUserLeaveHint () {

        //stopService(i);

        //super.onUserLeaveHint();

    //}

    private boolean isAppForeground() {

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        Iterator<RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            RunningAppProcessInfo info = i.next();

            if (info.uid == getApplicationInfo().uid && info.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) 
                {
                    return true;
               }
           }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onResume () {

        super.onResume();

        //name = "StartSt2";



        start.startAnimation(buttonRotate);

        highscores.startAnimation(buttonRotate);

        achievements.startAnimation(buttonReverseRotate);

    }

    public void onStop () {

        super.onStop();

        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);

        if (!isAppForeground()) {

            stopService(i);

            musicStopped = true;

        }

    }

    public void onStart () {

        super.onStart();

        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "KFKHK45345JHDADF");

        //stopService(i);

        //startService(i);

    }

    public void onRestart () {

        super.onRestart();

        if (musicStopped) {

        //stopService(i);

        startService(i);

        musicStopped = false;

        }

    }

    public void startMusicService () {

        startService(i);

    }

    public void stopMusicService () {

        stopService(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The only reason I didn't include any is because I literally just derived my existing MainActivity class from BaseGameActivity and the implement the onSignInSucceeded and onSignInFailed functions with nothing in them. So there isn't a whole lot to show except the rest of my game's code - gonna figure out how to paste it in here. 1000 lines or so...

Comment: Is the account you are using to sign-in listed as a services test account in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the app ID, defined in res/ids.xml is defined:

```
<string name="app_id">YOUR_APP_ID</string>
```

The app ID for Games is just a 12 or so digit number and comes from https://play.google.com/apps/publish under the games icon.

Next, make sure that your Android app is on the same project. If the two don't match, you can get errors like this.